# Calling REST API of a Flask app from another Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

I'm running two Flask apps (A & B) on my local machine. In Flask app B, I'm calling an endpoint from Flask app A.

The endpoint being called from Flask app A is: `/hello_world`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello_world", methods=["POST"])
def hello_world():
     a = request.json.get("a")
     b = request.json.get("b")
     return jsonify({a:b})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

In flask app B, the endpoint `/hi_world` is making a call to the above endpoint as follows:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hi_world", methods=["POST"])
def hi_world():
     a = request.json.get("a")
     b = request.json.get("b")
     paras = {"a":a, "b":b}
     response = requests.post(url="http://0.0.0.0:5000/",data=paras)
     print(response)
     return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5002,debug=True)
```

I use postman to make a POST call to the `/hi_world` where I pass the following dictionary in the request body `{"a":"Hello","b":"World"}`. However, I get a `<Response [404]>`. When I call the `/hello_world` directly from postman it works just fine with a `<Response [200]>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is a typo: you are going to `0.0.0.0/5000` not `0.0.0.0:5000`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Actually in my source code it is as you have wrote it. I just mistyped it here.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 to `hi_world`, then, can you make sure the route works in isolation? i.e. remove anything involving talking to the other endpoint

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a routable IP. It's a **bind address**. Use `127.0.0.1:5000` on the same machine

Comment: 0.0.0.0 will match the default route, which will likely route to localhost. Not amazing practice, but not necessarily a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second application you need to updated this line:

```
response = requests.post(url="http://0.0.0.0:5000/",data=paras)
```

to refer the full URL of the first application, like::

```
response = requests.post(url="http://0.0.0.0:5000/hello_world",data=paras)
```

Comment: loool oops, how did i miss that

Comment: Is it possible to have Flask apps A and B and in A have authentication and authorization and use it in requests in app B ?